# Running a single instance of software for multiple selected files by right click menu of windows using NSIS installer

Tags: windows, nsis, windows-shell

I have a software which runs fine for a single file using the right click menu of windows, but opens the multiple instances of the software when i select multiple files and click on the command from right click menu.

[image]

My current script for the command is this:

```
Section "Integrate Shred" SectionShred
    # register file association verb
    WriteRegStr HKCR "AllFileSystemObjects\shell\shred.bleachbit" "" 'Shred with BleachBit'
    WriteRegStr HKCR "AllFileSystemObjects\shell\shred.bleachbit\command" "" '"$INSTDIR\bleachbit.exe" --gui --no-uac --shred "%1"'
SectionEnd
```

Help me in editing above script so that a single instance runs for multiple selected files.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 ways to do this but they all involve adding additional code to your application:

- [IDropTarget](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/05/03/10006065.aspx) (WinXP+)
- DDE (Win95+ but deprecated)
- Implement you own custom handling with a mutex + `FindWindow` + `WM_COPYDATA`

If your target is Vista+ you can probably get away with a simpler version of the droptarget implementation by using one of the IExplorer* interfaces...

Comment: Thanks @Anders, I tried 1st option but I was unable to use it properly, if possibe can you please give me some example code by which I can understand more easily.

Comment: I linked to some example code in my answer. You might also want to change the tags on this question, this has nothing to do with NSIS it is more of a Windows shell related question...

Comment: Actually sir I wanted to know the code related to NSIS as using shell I had understood but I am not getting to integrate it with NSIS.... so if you have any idea of how to do it in windows then it will be very helpful...

Comment: The NSIS part is similar to what you already have, you just need to add the DropHandler under shellex.